# DAX historical data H1 interval

Tags: market-data, historical-data, history

I need pure DAX historical data on H1 interval (open, high, low, close). I can download data e.g from Dukascopy but this is DEU index (CFD for DAX) not DAX.

Where I can find good data (not CFD for DAX, not from MM broker etc.)?
Can be paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google finance for that

With i in seconds

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=3600&p=100d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=DAX&x=INDEXDB